# Bootstrap tab-pane active onclick

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

**index.html**

```html
<div class="ban_km font_bold">
 <a class="redrct_tab" href="Maintenance-schedule">know more</a>
</div>
```

**maintenance schedule.html**

```html
<ul id="leadbann" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"></li>
  <li role="presentation"></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="maintehance"></div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="warranty"></div>
</div>
```

Directly coming to my question. Whenever i click the know more link in **index.html** it will redirecting to the maintenance schedule page.

It's working fine. I need the second `<li>` and second `tab-pane` should get active class. First child active should be removed. How to make this through jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Is this static website? Or a let's say, MVC project? Are you using any layout.cshtml file?

It not, you should basically add active class to your second list element. You don't need Jquery for that.

```
 <div class="tab-content">
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="maintehance">

</div>

<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="warranty">

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's Static website

Comment: So you should just add active class to second tab and remove the first lists active class. You don't need Jquery for that : )

Answer (score 0):

HTML : (Replace lines in schedule.html)

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<ul id="leadbann" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class="active">
   Some Content
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    Some Content
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="div">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="maintehance">
    Some Content
  </div>

  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="warranty">
    Some Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```js
$(function(){
    $("ul li:nth-child(2)").addClass("active");
    $("ul li:nth-child(1)").removeClass("active");

    $("#div").find("div:nth-child(2)").addClass("active");
    $("#div").find("div:nth-child(1)").removeClass("active");
});
```

[Check in JSFiddle](//jsfiddle.net/shashikdmn/mb6gxat6/)